# Installing GeoPandas gives a WinError 126 (conda) /GDAL API (pip) error. How do I resolve it?

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, geopandas

I want to install GeoPandas. When I use 'pip install geopandas' I get an error saying this:

> A GDAL API version must be specified. Provide a path to gdal-config using a GDAL_CONFIG environment variable.

When I try using 'conda install geopandas' it throws an OSError 126.

I've tried downloading the geopandas.whl and try installing it that way, but this does not work either. I also tried downloading C++ which also did not help.

I have Python 3.7.4 and work on a Windows 10 system.

Edit: Full error using conda install

[image: First part of the error]

[image: Second part of the error]

Comment: On windows, the recommended way to install GeoPandas is using `conda` (otherwise you need to build GDAL and other dependencies from source, which is the error message you are seeing for pip install geopandas). Can you show the full error message you get with `conda install geopandas` ?

Comment: I added it as an edit to my OP

Comment: what error are u getting when u tried installing through geopandas,whl!! And did youInstall descartes, pandas, fiona, shapely, pyproj??

Comment: Installing any packagen, using conda, gives me this error. So it also gives an error when installing descartes, pandas, fiona, ...

Comment: @TiboGeysen there is clearly something wrong with your Anaconda installation (since installing any package fails) I would recommend to try to reinstall the full of Anaconda first.

Comment: @Joris I've tried this, didn't help. I used pip and installed the dependent modules first which solved the problem.

Comment: @TiboGeysen you could open an issue at https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues